# Elasticsearch multi-select facet functionality with child aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Given the following data:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/products/'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/products/product/_mapping' -d '{
    "product": {
        "_parent": {"type": "product_group"}
    }
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/products/product_group/1' -d '{
  "title": "Product 1"
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/products/product/1?parent=1 -d '{
    "height": 190, 
    "width": 120 
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/products/product/2?parent=1 -d '{
    "height": 120, 
    "width": 100
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/products/product/3?parent=1 -d '{
    "height": 110, 
    "width": 120
}'
```

Child aggregation on *product* results in the following facets:

Height

- 110 (1)
- 120 (1)
- 190 (1)

Width

- 120 (2)
- 100 (1)

If I now filter on *height 190*, what I would like is to have the height aggregation excluded from the filter so the results would be:

Height

- 110 (1)
- 120 (1)
- 190 (1)

Width

- 120 (1)

This is solvable with filter aggregation, but I'm not sure if it works or how the syntax is when using parent - child relations.

See http://distinctplace.com/2014/07/29/build-zappos-like-products-facets-with-elasticsearch/

What I've tried so far:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/products/product_group/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "filter": {
        "has_child": {
            "type": "product",
            "filter": {
                "term": {"height": 190}
            },
            "inner_hits": {} 
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "to-products": {
            "children": {"type": "product"},
            "aggs": {
                "height": {
                    "filter": {"match_all": {}},
                    "aggs": {
                        "height": {
                            "terms": {"field": "height", "size": 10}
                        }
                    }
                },
                "width": {
                    "filter": {
                        "and": [{"terms": { "height": [190]}}]
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "width": {
                            "terms": {"field": "width", "size": 10}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but If you want to have multiple aggregation inside child aggregation, you have to append parent type name before every field in aggregation.

here is modified query,

```
 curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/products/product_group/_search?pretty=true" -d'
    {
   "size": 0,
   "filter": {
      "has_child": {
         "type": "product",
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "product.height": 190
            }
         },
         "inner_hits": {}
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "to-products": {
         "children": {
            "type": "product"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "height": {
               "filter": {
                  "match_all": {}
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "height": {
                     "terms": {
                        "field": "product.height",
                        "size": 10
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "width": {
               "filter": {
                  "and": [
                     {
                        "terms": {
                           "product.height": [
                              190
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "width": {
                     "terms": {
                        "field": "product.width",
                        "size": 10
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

It wasn't mentioned anywhere in documentation, which is confusing to many users, I guess they treat child aggregation same as nested aggregation so same way to aggregate.