# Multiselect aggregation in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

I have a scenario where I need to allow a user to select the multiple values on the facet.

I have a facet called states: facet values are state1(20),state2(10),state3(30).

When I select the state1.I am receiving the 20 results, But the other 2 values are not coming from the elastic search. I need to allow the user to select state2 or state3 to have or operations.
I have found the solution in  [Elasticsearch multi-select facet functionality with child aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438570/elasticsearch-multi-select-facet-functionality-with-child-aggregation).
Can someone help me to convert this request to java request

Any Suggestions,
Thanks, In advance.
Sri

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you are designing your application and the corresponding Elasticsearch query. If you end up having state1 as a must condition in your query, you will obviously not see state2 and state3 coming up in the aggregate section of your query results. I think that you are using same query to get both data as well as facet. In such a case, this is expected behavior. You will need to separate out the aggregation and results query and use the aggregation query results to show facet for selection.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using "should" to get the details. How we can have a separate request for aggregations. If we did separate calls,  is that aggregation results count will match with the results?

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching within the same field, I believe your query - using should - would look like this:

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": {
                "terms": 
                    {"states": ["state1", "state2"] }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this will include results where state is either "state1" OR "state2".

Comment: searching won't be a problem..Problem is with the aggregation values. I need to get all the buckets respective of response.

Comment: don't think I fully understand the issue then. Can you add some steps to what the user does, and what you expect to happen after each step?